# select parent div for particular class

Tags: html, css

html...

```
<div id="main">
<div class="news"></div>
</div>
```

How could I assign css for `#main` id which has `.news` class with pure css ?

---

Is there something like `#main:only(.news){...}`?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why don't you just target the main id directly using `#main { /* Some CSS */ }`?

Comment: There is no parent selector in CSS.

Comment: the #main id is different in other page and different in .news page

Comment: @C-Link Well generally it's good practice not to repeat id's. They should only be used once. Why don't you just apply a different id?

Comment: I'm using joomla template so index.php will generate it

Comment: not yet possible... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector

Comment: You know that what you are asking doesn't make sense? You are targeting an ID... so just target the #main...

Comment: I would target the main but inside #main there is .news > How could I target ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I often use a body class to allow me to distinguish a common id from one page to another

```
<body class="news-page">
  <div id="main">
    <div class="news">
```

then your css can do thus

```
.news-page #main {
  background: blue;
{

.another-page #main {
  background: green;
}


.news {
  background: red;
}
```

Comment: Your code would be fine. But as far as I'm using joomla template, do you know joomla that generate body class differently.

Comment: I think I should accept your answer and ask new question for replacing body class for joomla.

Answer (score 2):

You could keep using the #main id and then apply a class to the same element with it's own styles that could override the default #main styles, something like

```
<div id="main" class="news">

</div>
```

Then you could write a css rule like this

```
#main.news {
 /* your css rules go here */
}
```

Comment: Sorry I was thinking it's a mistake. The index page generate all #main div with class .news then how could I assign the main for .news #main

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question? Using my answer above, you could retain all styles of #main on all other pages, then on the news page you could add the .news class to the #main div to allow you to style it differently.

Comment: all page will have #main and when assign .news in #main then it also will be in all page as I'm using joomla template.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?  You can target id="main" with #main and class="news" with .news.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>    
        <style type="text/css"
            #main { color: red; }
            .news { color: blue; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="main">
            This is #main
            <div class="news">
                This is .news
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try a parent child relationship something like

```
#main > div { 
   color:pink;
}
```